# Apache PIG - How is data distributed among reducers for a GROUP operation

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig

I was wondering how PIG does actually decide how to partition the data in the reduce phase and whether I can influence the data distribution to avoid unbalanced reducer load.

For example:

```
grouped_data = GROUP data BY (year, month, day) PARALLEL 10;
```

Is the possible to change the partition for example by:
1.) shuffling the data before the group operation
or
2.) changing the order of the variables in the tuple
???

Or do you suggest a different approach?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, in most situations, PIG uses Hadoop's default partitioner, which is the HashPartitioner.

```
public int getPartition(K key, V value, int numReduceTasks) {
  return (key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numReduceTasks;
}
```

You can use `PARTITION BY` to supply your own strategy.

```
B = GROUP data BY (year, month, day) PARTITION BY foo.bar.CustomPartitioner PARALLEL 10;
```